# How to exclude objects based on the field in a different model?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    field1 = models.BooleanField()
    field2 = ...

class Model2(models.Model):
    field21 = ...
    field22 = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
    objects = FilterManager()
```

and how to in FilterManager (Model1) exclude objects contains Model1.field1 = False?

My FilterManager:

```
class FilterManager(models.Manager):

    def optfilter(self, options = dict()):
         if options.has_key('option'):
             kwargs['field21'] = options['option']

         return self.filter(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Model2.objects.exclude(field22__field1=False)
```